# Using tkinter after to produce an animation

Tags: python, tkinter

**Background Information** - I'm attempting to create somewhat of animation for a frame object with TKinter with the following code:
from tkinter import Frame, Tk, Label, Button
import time

```
def runAnim():
    for width in range(0, 200):
        app.after(5000, lambda width = width: test_label.config(width=width))

app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x500")
test_label = Frame(bg="#222", width=0)
test_label.pack(side="left", fill="y")
test_button = Button(text="toggle", command=lambda: runAnim() )
test_button.pack(side="right")
```

**The problem** is that it this is not producing the desired behaviour. My understanding is that this should gradually increase the width every 5 seconds, however the 0-200 range seems to complete within these 5 seconds, rather than it being an increased width of 1 every 5 seconds.
Any solutions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `after(5000, …)` means 5 seconds after *right now, as `after` is being called*, not 5 seconds after some future point in time that tkinter can only guess by reading your mind.

So, you're just creating 200 callbacks, and scheduling them all to run 5 seconds from now. That's obviously not what you *want*, but it's what you're *asking for*, so that's what you get.

---

In general, you can't do loops like this in event-based programming. What you need to do is turn the loop inside-out: each step does one iteration, then schedules the next call for the next one.

---

The fully-general transformation looks like this:

```
def runAnim():
    iterwidth = iter(range(0, 200))
    stepAnim(iterwidth)

def stepAnim(iterwidth):
    try:
        width = next(iterwidth)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    test_label.config(width=width))
    app.after(5000, stepAnim, iterwidth)
```

---

While that works for any iterable, when you're just iterating over numbers, it's usually a bit nicer to turn the `for` loop into an explicit counter, which is easier to invert. (Yes, that's the opposite of the "usual `for` instead of `while` and `+= 1` when you're *not* inverting things. The difference is that here, we can't access the magic of `for` or `while`, and `while` is a lot less magical, and therefore easier to invert.)

```
def runAnim():
    stepAnim(0, 200):

def stepAnim(width, maxWidth):
    test_label.config(width=width))
    width += 1
    if width < maxWidth:
       app.after(5000, stepAnim, width, maxWidth)
```

---

However, in this particularly simple case, you might be able to get away with scheduling 200 callbacks, ranging from 5 to 1000 seconds into the future:

```
def runAnim():
    for width in range(0, 200):
        app.after(5000 * width, lambda width = width: test_label.config(width=width))
```

This *might* cause the timer to drift a lot more badly, or it might even choke up the scheduler and add lag to your program, but it's at least worth trying.

---

Speaking of drift:

Back at the start, I mentioned that `after(5000, …)` means 5 seconds after right now.

An `after` can fire a bit late. As [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) say: "Tkinter only guarantees that the callback will not be called earlier than that; if the system is busy, the actual delay may be much longer."

So, what happens if it fires after, say, 5.2 seconds? Then the second tick happens 5 seconds after *that*, at 10.2 seconds, not at 10 seconds. And if they're all firing a bit late, that adds up, so by the end, we could be 20 seconds behind.

Worse, what if `after` fires exactly at 5.0 seconds, but the `Label.config` takes 0.2 seconds to run? Then we're absolutely *guaranteed* to be 20 seconds behind. (Plus any additional error from `after` itself.)

If this matters, you need to keep track of the desired "next time", and wait until then, not until 5 seconds from whenever it is now. For example:

```
import datetime as dt

def runAnim():
    stepAnim(0, 200, dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(seconds=5):

def stepAnim(width, maxWidth, nextTick):
    test_label.config(width=width))
    width += 1
    if width < maxWidth:
       now = dt.datetime.now()
       delay = (nextTick - now).total_seconds() * 1000
       nextTick += dt.timedelta(seconds=5)
       app.after(delay, stepAnim, width, maxWidth, nextTick)
```

Comment: Instead of ` app.after(5000, lambda: stepAnim(iterwidth)` you can avoid using `lambda` by doing it this way: `app.after(5000, stepAnim, iterwidth)`

Comment: @BryanOakley Right, I forgot about that. It's new since Python 2.2 or so, so it's taken me a while to get used to it. :)